# Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... PHP Fatal error: Cannot declare class ..., because the name is already in use in

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I want to get coverage.xml for CodeCov.
PHP 8.0.2
PHPUnit 9.5.2
Xdebug 3.0.2

My class. It's very simple, just practice for code coverage
**src/Car.php**

```
<?php
/**
* This class is for car.
*/

class Car
{
 public function GetColor()
 {
   return 'Blue';
 }
}
```

Test file.
**tests/CarTest.php**

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__ .'/../src/Car.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
/**
 * @coversDefaultClass Car
 */
class CarTest extends TestCase
{
  /**
  * @covers Car::GetColor
  */
  public function testCarGoodColor(): void
  {
    $car = new Car();
    $this->assertSame('Blue', $car->GetColor());
  }
}
```

When I enter

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/ --coverage-clover ./coverage.xml
```

I get this message:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.0.2 with Xdebug 3.0.2
Configuration: /Applications/CI-CD/phpunit.xml

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.187, Memory: 8.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare 
class Car, because the name is already in use in /Applications/CI-CD/src/Car.php on line 8

Fatal error: Cannot declare class Car, because the name is already in use in /Applications/CI-CD/src/Car.php on line 8
```

How to resolve this issue with classes?

Comment: 1) Do you use Composer autoloader? If you do .. then you do not really need `include_once __DIR__ .'/../src/Car.php';` line as autoloader takes care of that (if it's used in both your app and PHPUnit files -- e,g, in bootstrap file). 2) Maybe you somehow have more than one file with `Car` class in your project? It may already be loaded by that time... Do a global (whole project) search. You can also check if a class with name is already registered with [get_declared_classes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php)

Comment: The right way was to make a global search. In my folder src/ I have an index.php, and there was require "Car.php". I don't know why, but it was a problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do not use require/include for classes. Let autoloader load the classes for you -- it does it well. And only use require/include for other stuff (e.g. load config / template or alike)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)

Problem was with

```
include_once __DIR__ .'/
```

../src/Car.php';

I fix it with autoload.
Also, I had **index.php** in **src/** and I add it to **ignore** for code coverage.